# several mpiruns in parallel on several nodes

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I want to run two programs using mpi in parallel in the same job script. In SLURM I would usually just write a script for sbatch (shortened):

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
mpirun program1 &
mpirun program2
```

This works fine.
The two programs will internally communicate with each other and coordinate execution. So overcommiting is fine. Moreover, they require each other and cannot run as stand-alone in the present configuration.

However, if I want to extend this to several nodes, e.g.

```
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=2
```

SLURM does *not* start the first job in the background. Instead, it starts in the foreground, fails because it does not find the second step and the second then also fails -- because it does not find the first.

I am a bit at a loss here because that is the suggested solution (e.g. [Run a "monitor" task alongside mpi task in SLURM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759221)) to similar problems and I do not see a reason why this should not work over several nodes. Indeed it does, for instance on PBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With slurm the main issue is that the user should use `srun` instead of `mpirun`, i.e.:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
srun --overlap program1 &
srun --overlap program2
wait
```

When running on multiple nodes, using `srun` is crucial, `--overlap` allows the job steps to share allocated resources, and `wait` ensures that all steps are finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your Multiple Program Multiple Data (MPMD) application like this:

```
mpirun -np x program1 : -np y program2
```

Comment: This is a cool feature that I did not yet know. I fear, this does not work since both programs were not written with this in mind and assume that they comprise all processes of the communicator. If I try this locally both programs stall basically from the start...
Similar issues have been reported (e.g. https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-solving/217997-multiple-parallel-cases-single-node-single-mpirun.html). And yes, one program is OpenFOAM.
I will give this some more tests and thoughts but I think this is no replacement for the background variant running well on one node.

Comment: Ok. I don't know whether it makes sense. You could try `nohup` command to run it in background. `nohup mpirun program1 & mpirun program2`

Comment: No luck with that either...